# Ubuntu: Python command not found but apt says it's already installed

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu and need to run a python script, but bash can't find python.

```
$ python main.py
bash: python: command not found
```

When I go to install it with apt I am told that it has already been installed.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python is already the newest version (2.7.12-1~16.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: @ChrisHunt It doesn't output anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was saved as python3 instead of python

Comment: As you instructions, I convert the programme from python2 to python3. But I don't, still it showing same error.

Comment: As per the apt-get output, this question is about python2. Why would you assume python2 is installed as python3?

Answer (score 2):

Try the command `which python` it will reveal the location of where your system has installed Python.

Then try adding the location revealed by `which python` to `PYTHONPATH` as the first answer [here](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/forum_thread.php?id=2755). It's a good place to understand this.

Comment: When I type "$which python" it doesn't output anything

Comment: @TylerHilbert if `which python` does not output anything, and if `python` results in the interpreter, then python is most likely not added to the path. Still follow the instructions in the link.